# Decay of K+ Meson

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams

In Griffiths Introduction to Elementary Particles we are asked to draw the Feynman diagram for The decay of The $K^{+}$ Meson into a photon, antimuon and muon-neutrino. I am confused by the Diagram in the solution which seems to be completely false as the photon is just a virtual particle and the K Meson is nowhere to be found. Am i missing something here?

The Solution from the Solution Manual:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solutions manual seems to have an error, you can check on the [author's page](https://www.reed.edu/physics/faculty/griffiths.html) if this has been corrected. The correct diagram for $K^+ \to \mu^+ \nu_\mu$ is:

[image]

In order to get the diagrams for $K^+ \to \mu^+ \nu_\mu+\gamma$, you can take this diagram and attach a photon to any charged line (any line except the neutrino).

Comment: I have actually checked the author's site but no list of errors for the solution manual exists there.

Comment: There's a line that says: `Corrections to the ISM have been incorporated into the current electronic version`, here I believe ISM refers to "Instructor's Solution Manual." The online version of the instructor's manual should have this incorporated.